# Is it OK to deglaze your stainless steel pan with a dash of acetic acid?

Tags: frying, deglazing

It's really effective and most of the acetic acid boils off. Sometimes I don't want the vinegar or wine tartness, but I still want to capture the flavors from the pan. Acetic acid is also much cheaper than vinegar.

Comment: I don't know it seems to be quite potent, I would just dilute in water to have a vinegar like ratio (4%-8% to water)

Comment: Acetic acid is much more potent, cheaper, doesn't add additional flavors and boils off at 118C. You dilute it with boiling water.